# $.mobile.changePage not updated url

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have two pages menu list and menu detail page. I change page from menu to menu detail using `$.mobile.changePage`. It's working fine, and append back button link on menu detail page runtime, when I click on back button first time work navigation fine and navigate to menu page, but when done same process(e.g. menu to detail then back menu) then back button contain url of menu to detail page not detail to mainu.
    Menu to detail page:

```
$('.menu_item').live("click",function(){
    $.mobile.changePage('menu_detail.html?iInfoId='+iInfoId+'&type='+ type + ext_link +'&iIMenuId='+this.id+'&order_type='+order_type, {transition: "slide"});
});
```

On menu detail page back button link append

```
$('#btn_back').attr('href','menu.html?iInfoId='+ iInfoId +'&type='+type+ext_link+'&order_type='+order_type);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem

Try this:

```
$('.menu_item').off('click').on('click', function() { }
```

.live causes the script to run the code twice for some reason, I can't figure out why. But the code .off.on works fine.